# dataLoader vs dataProvider performance for amStockCharts

Tags: amcharts, amstock

I am currently using data provider for passing json data loaded externally. this is a large data with olhcv data per minute for 1 month. I am experiencing slowness while running it on localhost. It is taking 8 seconds to render full data.

Recently I saw the dataLoader feature of amStockChart. But I am experiencing issues with replacing my dataprovider with dataLoader as I have customized too many things. Can I please know if its worth the effort of moving to dataLoader from dataProvider?

Comment: It's about the same, performance-wise, except you're moving the inline assignment into an AJAX request, which sounds pretty similar to what you're already doing with your custom code anyway. My [basic demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9c2b1b381749edb9bb994147983d2f22) is only a few thousand elements short of a full month, but I'm getting around 5 seconds when the file is not cached and 3-4 when cached timed from the `init` to `dataUpdated` events. You can try using millisecond timestamps or date objects to speed up the parsing a bit, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @xorspark . I am already using Date objects btw. You saved me a lot of efforts to prove which one is fast. There was a page in amcharts docs which said: "dataLoader allows you to replace dataProvider" which made me think dataLoader must be a faster option.

Comment: @xorspark can you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446791/conditional-chart-area-fill-in-amcharts-amstockcharts question please... I think only you are the one who can answer this question...